Can I use present perfect or past simple in this context: The first time I **have ever seen** it was five years ago

The first time I have ever seen it was five years ago.

To my knowledge, we should use past perfect tense in the bold part. But can I use present perfect or past simple instead to match with "was"?

Since the current "narrative reference time" is time of speaking, you can't use Past Perfect (which requires a reference time in the past). And because the actual time you're talking about was five years ago I don't think you should use Present Perfect either. You'd use Present Perfect if you're talking about something happening now - for example, "This is the first time I have done this". Note that "This is the first time I did this" and "This is the first time I do this" and "This is the first time I am doing this"  are all unacceptable.

@FumbleFingers This is the first time I have done this.=present, yes, sure//past: That was the first time I had done that. Because she says was, the other verb has to be in the  past perfect. The downvote on my answer [not blaming you at all] is competely silly.

@Lambie: it wasn't my downvote on your question, but for the sake of "fairness" I'll upvote it after i post this comment. I think yours may have been a bit later than Seowjooheng Singapore's, so it may not have been there when I upvoted that one. But if I could only cast one vote, it would be for Seowjooheng's anyway, since it more explicitly advises OP to avoid Past Perfect whenever it's not needed. Everryone's always telling Indians to avoid the continuous, but I sometimes feel like a voice in the wilderness trying to steer learners away from "pointless perfects!"

@FumbleFingers Look, in this case, it is needed. This: The first time I have ever seen it was five years ago. IS NOT grammatical. This: The first time I had ever seen it was five years ago. IS grammatical. How can you dispute that? It is not pointless there at all.

I guess that's why I didn't upvote you before. You seem determined to defend pointlessly complex The first time I had ever seen it was five years ago. I never suggested that Past Perfect was "incorrect" (whereas the OP's Present Perfect is completely wrong), But Seowjooheng just goes straight to promoting Simple Past The first time I ever saw it was five years ago. Note that we don't actually know the "narrative reference time" of the cited utterance, but Seowjooheng sensibly assumes it's "time of speaking", hence past perfect is not suitable. I'm up for that!

@FumbleFingers It's not that I defend it. It's that **we just don't know what the OP wants to say.  I actually provided three possibilities.  Not just one like our Singaporean friend or the single-verb answer  from our fir tree friend (yes, I know in German there are two n's).

@Lambie: Well, on the principle Don't feed the bears, I don't think we should give learners any encouragement to use Perfect forms, which they often overuse anyway. We've heard nothing from the OP about whether the cited utterance is Present Tense (the normal situation; narrative context is time of speaking) or part of a Past Tense narrative (for example, a book referring to events in the past). That second possibility is far less likely, so it should either be silently ignored or peremptorily dismissed, imho).

The present perfect expresses a situation that holds at the present, at the moment the statement is uttered. Today I can say, “I have been to the UK seven times.” Before my most recent trip I could say, “I have been to the UK six times.” But if today I wish to speak of the period between these two most recent trips, I would have to say, “I had been to the UK six times.”
The first seeing mentioned in your sentence happened five years before the moment of the sentence’s utterance. That’s why the past perfect or the simple past is required.

We don't generally use past perfect without a simple past lurking in the background. So: I had been to the UK six times before I went there this time. It can be express or implied.

You don't actually answer the question at all because you only have one verb.

We could use the past perfect if we are talking about the past and want to describe something that happened at an earlier time.  The example is set in the present, and hence past perfect is not suitable.
As the seeing, which happened in the past, has no relevance to the present, we don't use the present perfect either; we use the past simple:

The first time I [ever saw] it was five years ago.


It could be a mistake: The first time I had ever seen it was five years ago. We don't know which she is trying to say. Yes, The first time I saw it was five years ago is fine too. Your sentence is incorrectly bracketed.

Thanks, @Lambie.  The brackets are for the things changed, not the verb phrase in this case.

The period of time "was five years ago" precedes the first time I had ever seen it.

The first time I had ever seen it was five years ago.
Five years ago was the first time I had ever seen it.
[The sequence is easier to see in the second one but is the same in the first.]
The first time I ever saw it was five years ago. [alternative: simple past]

Versus: Today is the first time I have ever seen it.

I agree with your answer, excepting that I don’t understand its first sentence.

@PaulTanenbaum Is it better now? :)

I’m afraid not. Perhaps it’s ambiguity about comes before, and whether you are talking about syntax (words preceding other words) or chronology (events preceding other events)?

Disregard the downvote. The answer is grammatically correct.
